# Handling URL Redirections with HttpURLConnection or HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, url, https, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection

I recently ran into an issue while trying use HttpURLConnection to get the response code of a website, specifically `https://bobaguys.com`

Here is the code

```
URL url = new URL("https://bobaguys.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

And we see that we get an error `Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching bobaguys.com found.` After a tiny bit of investigation however, I realized that if I changed the URL to `http://bobaguys.com` or `http://www.bobaguys.com`, I get a redirection response of 301, with it seemingly being permanently moved to `https://www.bobaguys.com`. So I guess here is my first question. Why is `http://bobaguys.com` not redirected? Does the web server of the original site have to set up that redirection and they just never set it for `https://bobaguys.com`? And my second question is, how should I handle cases like this? I want to consider all these URLs as valid strings to feed to my function and return that the site is valid. There's the brute force option of just trying all the combinations of the two http and https protocols with www. and without www., but I feel like there must be a better way right?

Comment: You would have to ask the site webmaster why his redirects are like that.

Comment: *So I guess here is my first question. Why is `http://bobaguys.com` not redirected* You just said it *was* redirected.

Comment: `https://bobaguys.com` is also redirected, but the HTTP protocol never gets started because the TLS handshake fails because of server and/or certificate misconfiguration. The certificate needs to have `bobaguys.com` as one of its SANs, but it doesn't. If you ignore that error then you get a 301 redirect to `https://www.bobaguys.com`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Sorry, meant https://... edited